# Column join to merge values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with languages terms.

```
VAR   |  EN  |   ES   |  FR
---------------------------
CR   |  car | coche  | voiture
```

Default is English and it has all terms, however some other languages, like Spanish of French can have terms missing. I need to run a query and get the terms into an array based on the language, but if the term in that language is missing, I need it to use corresponding English term, instead of having blank value.

I was thinking along the following lines:

```
SELECT * 
FROM terms
WHERE lang = "ES"
```

But I need all VARs and I don't see how I can pull them that way... Just having a mental block, probably need more coffee...

Comment: Can you post examples of rows where items are missing, and the expected output for that row? I'm having trouble picturing what you're looking for.

Comment: How do you want the result exactly? Your terms should be 1-1 correspondence, so how do you want an array?

Comment: @Desolator I use a class that simplifies the query output, and creates an array but in general I need to replace actual terms in my content with $terms['cr']. Sorry, was that the question?..

Comment: Cannot understand your mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function this way:

```
SELECT var, IFNULL(es, en) FROM terms
```

so that if the value in `es` is null, then `en` will be returned.

Another option would be the more generic [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
SELECT var, COALESCE(fr, es, en) from terms
```

which just returns the first non null value of the list (in case you want to handle a series of fallback values).

Comment: Sorry, I also need var. Shouldn't it be SELECT var, COALESCE(es, en) from terms? I like simplicity of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of MySQL in front of me to check it, but I would try:

```
SELECT var,
       en, 
       CASE WHEN es IS NULL THEN en ELSE es END as 'es_or_en',
       CASE WHEN fr IS NULL THEN en ELSE fr END as 'fr_or_en'
FROM terms
```

Comment: You can simplify this to `IF(es IS NULL, en, es)`.

Comment: More simpler: `IFNULL(es, en)`

Comment: Yes, I didn't know `IFNULL`. Cristian's answer is the best.